# Jquery to copy first link to second ul and then change class of first link

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Short question:**
http://jsfiddle.net/wF4FH/2/
What I want is for Page1 to be right above Page2 and Page10 above Page 20 before I change the classes. This should work for any number of elements.

The code provided gives an "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'append' ".

**Long question:**
I'm having problem finding the correct way to insert an li element based on the first link. The problem is I cant use id's on my markup so I have to "walk through" each class and check for names. I might just make this a lot more complicated than it is because my first two solutions didn't work the way I thought they would.

html

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active">
    <a href="/">Start</a>
</li>
<li class="has-child">
    <a href="/page1">page1</a>
    <ul class="">
        <li>
            <a href="/page1/page2">page2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-child">
<a href="/page10">page10</a>
<ul class="">
    <li>
        <a href="/page10/page20">page20</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/page10/page30">page30</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

javascript

```
 //Copy first link to child ul li 
    var pageLinks = $("li.has-child > a:first-child");
    if (pageLinks != null) {
        //var dropdownMenus = $("li.dropdown  > a:first-child");
        for (var i = 0; i < pageLinks.length; i++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < pageLinks.length; x++) {
                if (pageLinks[i].innerHTML === pageLinks[x].innerHTML) {
                    pageLinks[x].childNodes.append(pageLinks[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Change css classes
    $("li.has-child").attr('class', 'dropdown');
    $(".dropdown ul").addClass("dropdown-menu");
    $(".dropdown a").attr("href", "#").addClass("dropdown-toggle").attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
```

strong text
What I want is for Page1 to be right above Page2 and Page10 above Page 20 before I change the classes. This should work for any number of elements.

When they are copied to the inner ul I change the top level menu item to a different class to work as a clickable dropdown men item.

The code provided gives an "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'append' ".

It is the navigation of a cms I cant change the markup on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$links = $('li.has-child').children('a:first-child');
if($links.length > 0){
    $links.each(function(i,link){
        $(link).next().prepend($('<li></li>').append($(link)))
    })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wF4FH/6/

You need .clone() method to copy elements..

**UPDATED**

```
$links = $('li.has-child').children('a:first-child');
if($links.length > 0){
    $links.each(function(i,link){
        $(link).next().prepend($('<li></li>').append($(link).clone()))
    })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wF4FH/7/

Comment: Nice, but it moves it instead of to copy it. The first link will be duplicate, indicating the area of the submenus it holds. I need to link it to a descition page in a submenu. Its to mimic bootstrap. Kind of like this but it shold say "Verksamhet" in the submenu as well as in the clickable menu. http://bindab.se/

Comment: Nice! Thanks! As a bonus, how would I put a line under the clone? Like the one here, under the menuitem "Preview" then Default link?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a jQuery object and you access it by numeric index, you're left with an HTML element. So `$('body')[0] == document.body`. This means that when you access `pageLinks[x]`, you're really getting a raw element. This means that you want `pageLinks[x].appendChild(pageLinks[i]);`, not `pageLinks[x].childNodes.append(pageLinks[i]);`

Comment: It gives Uncaught Error: HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3